# Fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found in compiling c file

Tags: zig

I downloaded `libwsclient` c library as `git clone https://github.com/payden/libwsclient.git`
Inside the generated folder `libwsclient` I wrote `build.zig` as:

```rs
const Builder = @import("std").build.Builder;

pub fn build(b: *Builder) void {
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
    const mode = b.standardOptimizeOption(.{});
    const lib = b.addStaticLibrary(.{
        .name = "wsclientlib",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "wsclient.c" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = mode,
    });
    b.installArtifact(lib);
}
```

And tried to build the library as `zig build` but I got the below:

```
[hasany@hasan-20tes1n300 libwsclient]$ zig build
zig build-lib wsclientlib Debug native: error: error(compilation): clang failed with stderr: /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/chrome-development-tool/libwsclient/wsclient.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

zig build-lib wsclientlib Debug native: error: the following command failed with 1 compilation errors:
/usr/bin/zig build-lib /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/chrome-development-tool/libwsclient/wsclient.c --cache-dir /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/chrome-development-tool/libwsclient/zig-cache --global-cache-dir /home/hasany/.cache/zig --name wsclientlib -static --listen=- 
Build Summary: 0/3 steps succeeded; 1 failed (disable with --summary none)
install transitive failure
└─ install wsclientlib transitive failure
   └─ zig build-lib wsclientlib Debug native 1 errors
/home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/chrome-development-tool/libwsclient/wsclient.c:1:1: error: unable to build C object: clang exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

This is a hint that you need to tell Zig to link libc.

You can do this in `build.zig` by adding

```
lib.linkLibC();
```

This is equivalent to adding the `-lc` argument to the `zig build-lib` command.

Answer (score -1):

"Porting" the wclient build system to the Zig build system might be possible, but there is a lot of (implicit) configuration in the current autogen+configure+Makefile.am build system it uses.  At a minimum the current wsclient build includes more files than just "wsclient.c" (there is also "base64.c" and "sha1.c").

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might have better luck if
you follow the [libwsclient build instructions](https://github.com/payden/libwsclient/blob/master/README.md) to build the wsclient library, then link the built library into your Zig program.